# ActiveRecord/ARel modify `ON` in a left out join from includes

Tags: sql, activerecord, left-join, arel

I'm wondering if it's possible to specify additional `JOIN ON` criteria using ActiveRecord `includes`?

ex: I'm fetching a record and including an association with some conditions

```
record.includes(:other_record).where(:other_record => {:something => :another})
```

This gives me (roughly):

```
select * from records 
left outer join other_records on other_records.records_id = records.id 
where other_records.something = another
```

Does anyone know how I can specify an extra join condition so I could achieve something like.

```
select * from records 
left outer join other_records on other_records.records_id = records.id 
    and other_records.some_date > now()
where other_records.something = another
```

I want my includes to pull in the `other_records` but I need additional criteria in my join.  Anything using ARel would also be great, I've just never known how to plug a left outer join from ARel into and `ActiveRecord::Relation`

Comment: Could you make your example more concrete? The something_else is a little hard to follow.

Comment: Just changed it to a different condition, basically, I want to be able to join on more than just the foreign key.

Answer (score 4):

I can get you close with ARel. **NOTE**: My code ends up calling two queries behind the scenes, which I'll explain.

I had to work out LEFT JOINs in ARel myself, recently. Best thing you can do when playing with ARel is to fire up a Rails console or IRB session and run the #to_sql method on your ARel objects to see what kind of SQL they represent. Do it early and often!

Here's your SQL, touched up a bit for consistency:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM records
  LEFT OUTER JOIN other_records ON other_records.record_id = records.id
    AND other_records.some_date > now()
WHERE other_records.something = 'another'
```

I'll assume your `records` model is Record and `other_records` is OtherRecord. Translated to ARel and ActiveRecord:

```rb
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Named scope that LEFT JOINs OtherRecords with some_date in the future
  def left_join_other_in_future
    # Handy ARel aliases
    records = Record.arel_table
    other   = OtherRecord.arel_table

    # Join criteria
    record_owns_other = other[:record_id].eq(records[:id])
    other_in_future   = other[:some_date].gt(Time.now)

    # ARel's #join method lets you specify the join node type. Defaults to InnerJoin.
    # The #join_sources method extracts the ARel join node. You can plug that node
    #   into ActiveRecord's #joins method. If you call #to_sql on the join node,
    #   you'll get 'LEFT OUTER JOIN other_records ...'
    left_join_other = records.join(other, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin).
                              on(record_owns_other.and(other_in_future)).
                              join_sources

    # Pull it together back in regular ActiveRecord and eager-load OtherRecords.
    joins(left_join_other).includes(:other_records)
  end

end

# MEANWHILE...

# Elsewhere in your app
Record.left_join_other_in_future.where(other_records: {something: 'another'})
```

I bottled the join in a named scope so you don't need to have all that ARel mixed in with your application logic.

My ARel ends up calling two queries behind the scenes: the first fetches Records using your JOIN and WHERE criteria, the second fetches all OtherRecords "WHERE other_records.record_id IN (...)" using a big list of all the Record IDs from the first query.

`Record.includes()` definitely gives you the LEFT JOIN you want, but I don't know of a way to inject your own criteria into the join. You could use `Record.joins()` instead of ARel if you wanted to write the SQL yourself:

```rb
Record.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN other_records' +
             ' ON other_records.record_id = records.id' +
             ' AND other_records.some_date > NOW()')
```

I really, really prefer to let the database adapter write my SQL, so I used ARel.

If it were me, I'd consider putting the additional join criterion in the WHERE clause. I assume you're asking because putting the additional criterion on the join makes the query's EXPLAIN look better or because you don't want to deal with NULLs in the other_records.some_date column when there aren't any related other_records.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a simple (equality) extra join condition it could simply be

```
record.includes(:other_record).where(:other_record => {:something => :another,
                                                       :some_date => Time.now})
```

But if you need the greater than comparison the following should do it.

```
record.includes(:other_record).where([
  'other_records.something = ? and other_records.some_date > ?',
   another, Time.now])
```

Hope that helps.